# Find unique max values for each row in DF with equal numbers

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
A <- rep(1, times = 3)
B <- 1:3
C <- c(1,3,2)
DF <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

Which makes:

```
> DF
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 1 2 3
3 1 3 2
```

I would like to create a new column that indicates the columname in which the max value for each row can be found but only if they are unique, otherwise I would like to give it an NA.

I have tried various options, however this one for example would always use the first column name in which the value was found as the max:

```
DF$max <- colnames(DF)[max.col(DF, ties.method = "first")]
```

Reulting in:

```
A C B
```

I would like to have

```
NA C B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of max values in each row using `rowSums`, turn the output to `NA` if they are more than 1.

```
col <- colnames(DF)[max.col(DF)]
col[rowSums(DF == do.call(pmax, DF)) > 1] <- NA
DF$max <- col
DF

#  A B C  max
#1 1 1 1 <NA>
#2 1 2 3    C
#3 1 3 2    B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the result of `ties.method = "first"` is equal to the result when `ties.method = "last"` is used.

```
i <- max.col(DF, ties.method = "first")
j <- max.col(DF, ties.method = "last")
DF$max <- colnames(DF)[i]
DF$max[i != j] <- NA

DF
#  A B C  max
#1 1 1 1 <NA>
#2 1 2 3    C
#3 1 3 2    B
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `pmap` for this purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DF %>%
  mutate(Max = pmap_chr(DF, ~ {
    x <- c(...)
    if(sum(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE)) > 1) {
      NA_character_
    } else {
      names(DF)[which(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE))]
    }
  }
                        ))

  A B C  Max
1 1 1 1 <NA>
2 1 2 3    C
3 1 3 2    B
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
DF$max <-  names(DF)[max.col(DF, "first")*NA^(rowSums(DF == do.call(pmax, DF)) > 1)]
DF$max
[1] NA  "C" "B"
```